# Cannot update a component (`AuthProvider`) while rendering a different component (`RequireAuth`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working with `react-auth-kit`

I have this button, when we click on it the function `Auth` is launched

**SignIn file**

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const auth = async () => {
        const response = await authUser(body);
        const token = await response.text();

        if (token === 'User not Found') {
            setError(true);
        } else if(response.status === 200){
            signIn({
                token: token,
                tokenType: 'Bearer',
                expiresIn: 140,
                authState: {
                    user: phoneNumber,
                }
            });

            navigate('/account');
        }
    }

return (
 <button className="signin__enter_enterbutton" onClick={auth}>
       Увійти
       <svg className="signin__enterbutton-arrow" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M1.29231 12L10.1538 3.13846V11.0769H12V0H0.923077V1.84615H8.86154L0 10.7077L1.29231 12Z" fill="black" />
       </svg>
 </button>
)
```

**App file**

```
const routes = [
  {
    element: <OutletPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'account',
        element: <RequireAuth loginPath="/sign-in"><Account /></RequireAuth>
        // element: <Account />
      }
    ]
  }
];

return(
 <div className="app">
      <CartContext.Provider value={{ numberCart, setNumberCart }} >
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </CartContext.Provider>
 </div>
)
```

Oh and if i delete `element: <RequireAuth> <Account /> </RequireAuth>` in `App.js` file and I'll just leave `<Account />` everything is gonna work either

**OutLet file**

```
  const [isFilter, setIsFilter] = useState(false);
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname.includes('catalog')) {
      setIsFilter(true);
    } else if (!location.pathname.includes('catalog')) {
      setIsFilter(false);
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <NavBar />
      <div className='app__navCatalogPlusPage'>
        {(!isFilter && location.pathname !== '/hookah-catering') &&
          <div className='app__WithoutFooter_navCatalog'>
            <Navigation />
            <Catalog />
          </div>
        }
        <Outlet />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
```

**Index file**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider authType='cookie' authName='_auth' cookieDomain={window.location.hostname} cookieSecure={true} >
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

In `SignIn` `response` receives a response from `authUser()` that function takes `body` it is just password and login and will return Bearer Token if everything is okay. Then i convert response into a text and check that we have not received `'User not Found'` if not received, write down paramethers in `react-auth-kit` function `signIn()` and then call `react-router-dom` function `useNavigate()` and there is main problem i will get this type of error [image: error][image: error]

in the second image we can see some error called `auth` in `SignIn` file of the fifty-seventh line on this line i have a `navigate('/account');` code, and if i delete it error will gone BUT useNavgate() is imoportant bacause only it can work with `React Routes` in correct way and i have no idea why `react-auth-kit` cannot work with `react-router-dom` and how to fix it

Comment: You should add `AuthProvider` and `RequiredAuth` here

Comment: We can't help address issues with code we can't see. Please [edit] to include *at least* the two files/components listed in the error as part of a complete [mcve].

Comment: Already done, in `index.js` file i added `AuthProvider` and `RequiredAuth` in `app.js`

Comment: What kind of file i did not include?

Comment: Sorry if the request was unclear. We're asking to see the `AuthProvider` component code, supposedly the component that is being updated, and the `RequireAuth` component code, supposedly the component triggering the update.

Comment: i just add `index.js` file

Comment: how can i show you guys this code? That is just npm package i can not do anything with it

Comment: You don't own either of the `AuthProvider` or `RequireAuth` component code? Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Yes, sir, it is just npm package, i surfing the internet in search of some instrument which will give me opportunity to provide some authorizations for my web site. It is not nessesary to use this kind of authorizations if you do have another way i can try it, i heard about `Auth0` do you know if this what i need?

Comment: give me a couple of minutes

Comment: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-beaver-cgqhno?file=/src/container/SignIn.jsx) here we go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253309/discussion-between-3dmax-and-drew-reese).

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the `react-auth-kit` code. https://github.com/react-auth-kit/react-auth-kit/issues/1193 Looks like there is one possible [workaround](https://github.com/react-auth-kit/react-auth-kit/issues/1193#issuecomment-1404453234) solution.